# Check BOOL value with aggregate functions in NSPredicate

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data, ios6, nspredicate

I have two entities called folder and file, Folder has one to many relationship with file entity. File entity has a property called completedStatus which is a BOOL. I need to check which all files have this completedStatus == TRUe IN a particular folder.file NSOrderedSet.

---

For this I tried this way, by reading the docs, but it is not working

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"completedStatus = 1 IN %@", file.note]];
```

So Please help me out.

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: You have an array of `File` objects, and you want all files in that array with `completedStatus = 1`?

Comment: @MartinR, thanks for replying, I want the same as you have asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
NSArray *files = ... // your array of File objects
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"completedStatus = 1"];
NSArray *completedFiles = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

**UPDATE:** `NSOrderedSet` does not have methods to filter with predicates. But you can convert the ordered set `folder.file` to an array:

```
NSArray *files = [folder.file array];
```

and then continue as above.

*Alternatively,* you can make a fetch request on the *File* entity with the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"completedStatus = 1 && folder = %@", theFolder]
```

assuming that you have defined the inverse relationship `folder` from the *File* entity to the *Folder* entity.

Comment: Hey @Martin R, sorry, actually I want to get it from NSOrderedSet and not from an NSArray.Here folder.file mentioned above is NSOrderedSet

Comment: Thanks a ton, But I want to know, what went wrong in my above code, using the aggregate function "IN", can you explain me.

Comment: @Ranjit: "IN" is used as "attribute IN %@", not "condition IN %@", therefore your syntax was not correct.